# Can't do the CakePHP autocomplete tutorial

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP, I am trying to create a autocomplete function from a textbox, using this tutorial: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/matt_1/2011/08/07/yet_another_jquery_autocomplete_helper_2

I keep getting a
`Error: AutoCompleteHelper could not be found.
Undefined index: autoCompleteText`

I am unsure how to fix this as I have tried relocating the files and still the same error.

I create the below files and copy the code from the tutorial,
create the auto_complete.php in the view/helpers directory,
and create webroot/js/views/helpers/auto_complete.js.

controller - Tests
function auto_complete

```
class TestsController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session','Js','AutoComplete');

 public function auto_complete() {
 $this->loadModel('Tutor');
 debug( $this->params);


    $terms = $this->Tutor->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Tutor.first_name LIKE' => $this->params['url']['autoCompleteText'].'%'
        ),
        'fields' => array('Tutor.first_name'),
        'limit' => 3,
        'recursive'=>-1,
    ));
    $terms = Set::Extract($terms,'{n}.Tutor.first_name');
    $this->set('terms', $terms);
    $this->layout = '';    
}
```

view
 auto_complete.ctp

```
<?php 
echo $this->AutoComplete->input(
    'Tutor.first_name',
    array(
        'autoCompleteUrl'=>$this->Html->url( 
            array(
                'controller'=>'tests',
                'action'=>'auto_complete',
            )
        ),
        'autoCompleteRequestItem'=>'autoCompleteText',
    )
);

  if(isset($terms)) {
    echo $this->Js->object($terms);
  }

       echo $this->Form->create('');

            echo $this->Form->input('type', array('label' => 'Choose' ));
           echo $this->Form->end('send'); 

 ?>
```

I had a good look around previous posts and I really couldnt solve the problem.
[Cakephp form input with autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594181/cakephp-form-input-with-autocomplete)

Comment: I had a long look at other posts and I did a few hours research TBH

Comment: My post got -1 after 5 sec of me posting so I doubt anyone has read it. What is going on here?

Comment: What version of Cake are you running?

Comment: 2.5.X  Not sure what do here

Comment: Are you simply trying to dynamically call a view helper from your view?  Hard to tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you're looking at is for CakePHP 1.x (it's from August 2011, Cake 2 came out in October '11), but you're running Cake 2.5. The naming standards have changed between 1.x and 2.x, so Cake can't see your helper.

**First:** Your main problem is that you're naming your helper `auto_complete.php` when it should be `AutoCompleteHelper.php`.

**Second,** you are placing it in the wrong directory. In Cake 1.x, helpers lived under `/view/helpers/`. In 2.x, they live under `/View/Helper/`.

**Third,** regarding the undefined index error, you need to understand how this helper works in the first place, and why you're implementing it incorrectly.

The controller action `auto_complete` should not have a view. It's just a data source. When you use the helper, it loads the Javascript, which does its magic by polling `/auto_complete?autoCompleteText=stringgoeshere`.

You might notice that you removed `$this->layout = 'ajax';` from the controller action, probably because your toolbars weren't rendering. They weren't supposed to. It's just a datasource, it NEEDS the ajax layout, and there should be no view on that action.

Because you were trying to put a form on your `auto_complete` action and not on another action, the helper was looking for the query parameter `autoCompleteText`, not finding it, and displaying an error.

You can solve this by changing the `auto_complete` action back as close as possible to how it was in the example, deleting `auto_complete.ctp`, and by trying to use the helper in the correct view, like `add.ctp`.

**Fourth:** You shouldn't be using jsHelper anymore. It's been deprecated in 2.5 and is going to disappear in the future. Basically, the tutorial is obsolete.

However, it's really easy to just replace `$this->set('terms', $terms);` with `return json_encode($terms)` and write your own piece of JS to make an AJAX call. I suggest incorporating [Typeahead.js.](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)

**Finally:** You should consult the [1.x -> 2.x migration guide,](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#helpers) and as well, once you get your helper running you've got some other typos in your code that will break it anyway- "`Ttuor.first_name`", for example. Good luck!

Comment: I fixed that error and yes I also tried AutoComplete.php without success(same error) and I also tried all combinations without hyphen names. I just dont get why this doesnt work as I looked at the migration guide. I just cant find this helper no matter what name I give it and without an example I am simply guessing

Comment: Is there a working example anywhere? I seem to get voted down every time I ask a question so it would be easier if I can see something working

Comment: I can find the helper so that is fixed. I stil get an error so is this because of cakephp 1.X? I cant solve it sorry .Undefined index: autoCompleteText

Comment: I appreciate the time and effort you put in. I didnt know the tutorial was  out of date and why an earth is it on the docs anyway? I had trouble again with it. Unless I see a working example I am not going to waste anymore time on this.  This is not your fault BTW